# page turning effect on macosx

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

what is the best way to reproduce a page turning effect (like the one in iBooks) under Mac OS X?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven’t personally done this. That being said, my advice is to take a look at [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves), which implements an iBooks-like page turning interface for iOS, and try to port it to Mac OS.